# ASP.Net Web API XML Serialization ArrayOf

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net Web API (WCF 4.0) method to return a `List<WorkItem>`.

This is returning an xml with ArrayOf... in the form

```
<ArrayOfworkitem xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AgilePortalServices.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <workitem>
        <id>28</id>
        <title>Test</title>
    </workitem>
    <workitem>
        <id>27</id>
        <title>Test Bug</title>
    </workitem>
</ArrayOfworkitem>
```

But I want it returned as

```
<workitems>
    <workitem>
        <id>28</id>
        <title>Test</title>
    </workitem>
    <workitem>
        <id>27</id>
        <title>Test Bug</title>
    </workitem>
</workitems>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be due to the serializer using the WCF XML serializer, instead of the default XmlSerializer.

You can modify this by stting the default formatters (and you can replace this with a 3rd party if you choose to).

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

More info at [this web-api overview](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter)

Comment: Where do I put this code - I studied the link which suggests the Application_start method in Global.asax.cs but I get an Error: The name 'GlobalConfiguration' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I just re-read your question. Apologies, are you using WCF4.0? Or WebAPI? You should create a new WebAPI (ASP.Net 4.0) Project, not a WCF project.

Comment: Wasn't using a WebAPI project. Will try that now. Thanks