# Remove <ArrayOf. From MVC Web Api response

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following response from a standard MVC 4 WebApi project;

```
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Product>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
<Category>Groceries</Category>
<Price>1</Price>
</Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

I am trying to make it so that it returns

```
<Products>
<Product>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Tomato Soup</Name>
<Category>Groceries</Category>
<Price>1</Price>
</Product>
</Products>
```

I have found many reference to various methods that supposedly solve this, none work;

Changing the default serializer does not work.

Creating a customer serializer for `Product` does not work.

Creating a new class that has `List<Product>` exposed with suitable XmlRoot and XmlElement attributes does not work.

Adding `Datacontract` attributes does not work.

Adding `CollectionDatacontract` attributes does not work.

This appears to be so simple to everyone else, except me!

Comment: Have you tried using the setting [shown in this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263345/asp-net-web-api-xml-serialization-arrayof). Also, are you using the release version of the Web API?

Comment: Yes, tried that and yes, it is release version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using the XmlSeriazlier instead:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

And then try defining a class that derives from the collection of Product, and use [XmlRoot("Products")] to rename the element name from 'ArrayOfProduct' to 'Products'.

For example, instead of using List, use the class Products:

```
[XmlRoot("Products")]
public class Products : List<Product> { }

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

ApiController's action:

```
    public Products Get()
    {
        return new Products()
        {
            new Product() 
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Tomato Soup", 
                Category = "Groceries",
                Price = 1
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to to what you did but also change the `Product` xml element to something else? I cannot find a way to set the right attribute on the class to change the name...

Comment: 2Tallmaris: use [DataContract] attribute to decorate a class or/and properties

Comment: What is `config` in your code?  Do you mean `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;` ?

Comment: `config` is the argument that gets passed to method `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` in `App_Start/WebApiConfig`.

Comment: works good, still struggling to remove xmlns. xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" any idea? I tried  [XmlRoot("Orders", Namespace=null)] that did not work

Comment: To remove namespace go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860491/how-to-remove-namespace-from-web-api-response

Comment: In this way the help pages does no work anymore